# Why does the Android SDK show Android 10.0+ (R) instead of 11.0?

Tags: android-sdk, android-11

If I open Android Studio and then open the SDK manager, I see 10.0+ (R). I checked for updates, but no other updates. Why is it 10.0+, instead of 11.0?

[image]

Comment: Android R/10+ was the name that was used in the beta phase of Android 11. I would assume that Android SDK manager does not update this name or Google forgot to change it to Android 11 after publishing the final release of Android 11.